# In Sublime Text how to copy line without end of line character

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

It is very useful that in ST3 you can copy a whole line with just ctrl+c, the only problem is that this command also copies the "return" or new line character, so for example when you copy a line and paste in a console it will run the command immediately. This is undesirable because I will want to first edit the command before running it. This forces me to manually highlight the line.

Is there a plugin or an easy way to cope the line where the cursor is without including the new line character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the default behavior by creating a Sublime Text macro and  a key bind for it on the `Ctrl+C` key:

**Packages/User/SelectLineNoEOL.sublime-macro**

```
[
    { "command": "move_to", "args": { "to": "hardbol" } },
    { "command": "move_to", "args": { "to": "eol", "extend": true } },
    { "command": "copy" },
]
```

**Default.sublime-keymap**

```
    { "keys": ["ctrl+c"], "command": "run_macro_file",
        "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/SelectLineNoEOL.sublime-macro"},
        "context":
        [
            { 
                "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal",
                "operand": true, "match_all": false,
            },
        ],
    },
```

[image]

I think I had saw another thread with a plugin which does this, but I could not find it.

Related threads:

1. [forum#14576](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-disable-selecting-newline-on-triple-click/14576) How to disable selecting newline on triple click?
2. [forum#14933](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/st3-copy-blank-line-using-yy-p-vi-paste-one-extra-line/14933) [ST3]Copy blank line using yy;p (Vi), paste one extra line

Comment: how would one do this by binding it to the mouse triple click in essence replacing the standard triple click behavior?

Comment: See: [SublimeForum#Double click redefinition](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/double-click-redefinition/17318) for mouse binding example.