# How to copy line in Sublime without new line

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Sublime when you have nothing selected and click `ctrl+c` you will copy whole line with the new line. How to remove that new line, so `ctrl+c` will copy only current line.

I'm using Sublime on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a direct setting that has this effect on the copy of a line when nothing is selected (other than turning off that ability entirely) but you can still achieve this.

One would be to create a macro that selects the entire line but without the newline on the end and then does the `copy` (or `cut` if you want it to work that way too), and then bind the keys for `copy` and/or `cut` to execute the macro if the selection is empty.

An example of that can be found in:
[How to copy line without end of line character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206543/in-sublime-text-how-to-copy-line-without-end-of-line-character)

This will definitely work, but it does have the effect of altering the selection to encompass the whole line, which at the least changes the location of the cursor from where it is to the end of the line.

If that is not desirable, then the way forward is a plugin that adjusts the clipboard operations to not include the newlines.

An example of that would be:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ExtendedEmptyCopyPasteEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    """
    Every time the cut or copy commands are executed in a file while all of the
    selections are empty, trim away the trailing newlines on the copied lines.
    """
    def on_post_text_command(self, view, cmd, args):
        # If copy or cut was just executed and every selection in the view was
        # empty, trigger our logic.
        if cmd in ("copy", "cut") and all([len(s) == 0 for s in view.sel()]):
            text = sublime.get_clipboard().split('\n')
            sublime.set_clipboard("\n".join([t for t in text if t != ""]))
```

This plugin listens for a `copy` or `cut` operation to finish, and then, if all of the selections are empty, adjusts the text on the
clipboard so that it doesn't include newlines at the end of any of the copied lines.

See this YouTube video (disclaimer: created by me) on [How to use plugins in Sublime Text](https://youtu.be/lBgDilqulxg) if you're unsure of how to set the plugin up.

Comment: But how to add that plug to a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @IGRACH you don't; as soon as you put it in place it will automatically adjust any cut and copy operations that you take without you having to do anything else.